# Getting latest Versioning Data

Tags: sql

I have a table which does versioning with an ID and a GUID.
The ID increases, but the GUID is static allowing for versioning control.

For example:

```
ID     GUID        Data
01     ASD         Something
02     ASD         Something Changed
03     ASD         Something Changed Again
04     DSA         Something Else
05     DSA         Something Else Changed
```

So the question is, how do you get the latest data, so you end up with:

```
03     ASD         Something Changed Again
05     DSA         Something Else Changed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        GUID VARCHAR(10),
        Data VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 01,'ASD','Something'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 02,'ASD','Something Changed'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 03,'ASD','Something Changed Again'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 04,'DSA','Something Else'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 05,'DSA','Something Else Changed'


SELECT  *
FROM    @Table t
WHERE   t.ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) ID 
              FROM @Table 
              WHERE GUID = t.GUID GROUP BY GUID)
```

*You should probably try to performance check a couple of solutions ( such as the one provided by @Rubens Farias) , and see what works best for you given the indexes you have.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.guid, t1.Data
FROM   table t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id, guid
       FROM table GROUP BY guid ) t2
       ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.guid = t2.guid
```